# clamav-daemon start condition failed, /var/lib/clamav/daily.{c[vl]d,inc} was not met

Tags: linux, email-server, anti-virus, systemctl, clamav

After installing Modoboa(Open Source Mail Hosting), I Tried to start clamav-daemon, but i faced start condition failed.

```
    systemctl status clamav-daemon.service
    clamav-daemon.service - Clam AntiVirus userspace daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/clamav-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/clamav-daemon.service.d
           └─extend.conf
   Active: inactive (dead)
Condition: start condition failed at Fri 2021-01-15 04:19:06 EST; 33min ago
           └─ ConditionPathExistsGlob=/var/lib/clamav/daily.{c[vl]d,inc} was not met
```

Below it showed the problem, conditionPathExistsGlob=/var/lib/clamav/daily.{c[vl]d,inc} was not met.
I couldn't start the service with systemctl or other commands.
After some troubleshoots, I found out that /var/lib/clamav is empty and there should be some .cvd update file.
Also I couldn't update the clamav with this command (show me 403 error):

```
sudo clamav-freshclam
```

what can I do now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some sort of tries, finally I downloaded daily.cvd and main.cvd manually with wget command directly from [clamav.net/downloads](https://www.clamav.net/downloads) and move them to my server with scp command and put them to /var/lib/clamav , then restart service and it worked!

```
systemctl restart clamav-daemon.service
systemctl status clamav-daemon.service
    clamav-daemon.service - Clam AntiVirus userspace daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/clamav-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/clamav-daemon.service.d
           └─extend.conf
   Active: active (running)
```

Comment: That's good that you got clamd to start, but it seems that clanav-freahclam may still be broken, and if so you won't get virus updates.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman based on 403 error, I think this is an error because of my server location where is IRAN, many companies unfortunately do sanctions and limitations for Iranians. I will change my server location soon to out of IRAN.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Good luck.

Comment: It works, thanks Omid.

Answer (score 1):

Complementary to Omid's answer, you can manually download the `.cvd` files from the mirror below and place them in `/var/lib/clamav`.

- https://database.clamav.net/main.cvd
- https://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd

(Thanks to [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/114004/1636166))